# Передать значение переменно JS в Rails функцию

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Во view я вызываю функцию `<%= escape_javascript render_statuses_select_box %>`, которая в свою очередь определена в хелпере. Данная функция у меня принимает параметры. Каким образом значение, полученное таким образом: `$("#my_id").val()` передать в эту функцию?

Comment: Вы хотите передать в Ruby'шный метод значение, получаемое через JS со страницы на клиенте? Так что ли?

Comment: @D-side, да, для этого делаю POST запрос, где передаю значение JS, а вот как дальше быть не знаю, этот метод `escape_javascript render_project_select_box` в контроллере не отрбатвает

Comment: Приведите минимальный пример для воспроизведения того, с чем вы столкнулись. Пока в голову приходит два ответа: (1) никак, (2) передать это значение заранее в исходный запрос.

Comment: Или используйте гем https://github.com/gazay/gon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Передать js-переменную на сервер через AJAX.
2. На сервере назначить @переменную
3. `<%= escape_javascript render_statuses_select_box %>` сделать при помощи unobtrusive javascript.